# How do you evaluate a small piece of code?

Tags: code-reviews

I'm creating a website based on users' code, a place where they can share code in a social way and one of the features I'm currently developing is Code Review.

This feature will allow users to evaluate code in certain aspects, from the top of my head I came out with things like:

- Legibility,
- Performace and
- Modularity.

What are the general characteristics that you evaluate when reviewing code?

Comment: This is a pretty subjective area. Creative coders do not always like code metrics any more than they like being rated by HR department on the scale 1 to 5.

Comment: Yep, i know it. Metrics and values could be cold but users will be also having to say way, so this way i think everyone could learn something with it

Comment: @guiman To get a better feel how code reviews are done, you should consider joining [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although still in beta there are quite a few great reviews there. Check them out, and I'm pretty sure you'll get a very good idea how to evaluate code.

Comment: And also make sure you read [this relevant question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120244/code-review-is-it-subjective-or-objectivequantifiable)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, most languages have some form of a lint program (i.e. [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) for Javascript, [FlexPMD](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD) for Actionscript, [pep8](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) for Python, etc.).

I would strongly suggest relying on standards set by the respective communities and using OS tools to parse code that you're hosting. If you were to couple this with peer reviews, you'd have yourself a pretty strong code review system. Linting is something that *should* be in any strong developer's pipeline, so I'd expect that most developers would like having this built into an automated system for them rather than having to build it into their pipelines (i.e. makefiles) themselves.

Comment: This is just great, really. I'll be considering building something to allow linting

Answer (score 0):

You mention performance, will your website have the ability to measure this?

If so, I would think the most important thing to measure would be does it give the correct answer?

Next you could measure memory usage and speed as secondary goals.